# Turn on namespace mode with Python xml.sax

Tags: python, xml, sax

Yikes, I can't seem to turn on namespace mode and get my contentHandler's `startElementNS` and `endElementNS` called.  Instead it is still calling `startElement` and `endElement`.  Here's how I'm setting it up:

```
source = open(sourceFileName)
xml_parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
handler = MyContentHandler()
xml_parser.setContentHandler(handler)
xml_parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces, True)
xml.sax.parse(source, handler)
```

How do I turn on namepace mode so it calls `startElementNS` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line (`xml.sax.parse(source, handler)`) creates a new parser. You are not using the `xml_parser` object for which you have set up namespace mode.

It should work if you change this line to

```
xml_parser.parse(source)
```